# In a min-heap with n elements with the smallest element at the root,

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

In a min-heap with n elements with the smallest element at the root, the 7th smallest element can be found in time.

1. Θ(nlogn)
2. Θ(n)
3. Θ(logn)
4. Θ(1)

My understanding: 
Time to find the smallest element on a min-heap- one retrieve operation - Θ(1)
Time to find the second smallest element on a min-heap- requires 2<sup>2</sup>−1 = 3 check operations to find the second smallest element out of 3 elements — Θ(1).

Time to find the 7th smallest element - requires O(2<sup>7</sup>−1) = O(127) check operations to find the seventh smallest element out of 127 possible ones — Θ(1).

In short if the number of required operations is independent of the input size n, then it is always Θ(1).
(Here, we are doing a level order traversal of the heap and checking the elements).

Or I can look this way too: If we are not allowed to traverse the heap and allowed only default heap-operations, we will be restricted with doing Extract-min 7 times which would be O(n).

My doubt is about which way is correct what should be the answer.

Comment: Do you want to find the item without modifying the heap? Or is it okay to just remove the minimum item seven times?

Comment: Are the data encapsulated and inaccessible?  If you can directly inspect the underlying array, you can directly see the first 127 elements in constant time without altering the heap, and Matt Timmermans' answer should be the correct one.  Remember that big-O is about how a problem scales as a function of n, not about how long it takes for a given n, so the constants are ignored even if they're ginormous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting min in a min heap takes `log(n)` time and because you are limiting to the 7th position ( a constant ) the time taken is still of the order of `log(n)`.

If you are trying to find 7th smallest element, one way to do it is extract the top element 6 times from the heap and then read ( not extract ) the top of the heap. That is your 7th smallest element. Your running time is still of the order of `log(n)` because you are removing constant number of times from the heap. Now you may want to insert the 6 elements back into the heap. Each insert has worst time of `log(n)`, this is still `log(n)` because 6 is constant.

Comment: All of that's true, but since the 7th smallest item cannot be deeper than 7 levels into the heap, it's one of the top 127 elements and independent of n.  Thus it can always be found in O(1) time, albeit with a large constant.  That will beat O(log n) for sufficiently large n.

Comment: @pjs Exactly. The complexity in general is O(k log n). Finding the kth smallest can be done in O(n) time (quickselect), but it destroys the heap. Of course, rebuilding the heap is O(n), as well.

Answer (score 4):

A min-heap is a specific arrangement of nodes, which you can traverse to find the 7th-smallest element in O(1) time, because you must visit at most 127 nodes.

A priority queue is an abstract data type that provides an extract-min operation, but which is not necessarily implemented with a min-heap that you could traverse in this way.

Comment: what if input has 127 1s, 127 2s, 127 3s 127 4s 127 5s 127 6s and one 7? 7th smallest element is 7 in this case, how do we traverse in this case?

Comment: @SomeDude In that case, you'll demonstrate that your smallest 7 elements are all 1 after visiting no more than 127 nodes.